# java shut down hook not work?

Tags: java, swing

I develop java swing application that measure bandwidth traffic
but i hope when pc became shut down the application save total send and recive 
traffic to file.
when i use shutdownhook in my code and shut down my pc
the file not save!
any body can help me?`
i use java on win7_64

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, IOException, URISyntaxException, Exception {

        NewClass n=NewClass.getInstance();
       Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                    saveHistory();//save send and recive traffic to file
                    System.out.println(1);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(BandWidthMeter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }, "Shutdown-thread"));
   }    
}

     void saveHistory() throws IOException{
         Date date=new Date();
         SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm");
         String format1 = format.format(date);
         //convert traffic to kiloByte
         double session_Send=(double)send/1024;
          double session_Recive=(double)recive/1024;
         String row=format1+"-"+String.valueOf(session_Send)+"-"+String.valueOf(session_Recive);
        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("src/bandwidthmeter/history.txt"),true)) {
            fw.append(row);
            fw.append("\n");
        }
        try ( //update total.properties
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("src/bandwidthmeter/total.properties")) {
            //convert traffic to megabyte
            double sessionSend=(double)send/1048576;
            double sessionRecive=(double)recive/1048576;
            totalSend+=sessionSend;
            totalRecive+=sessionRecive;
            prop.setProperty("totalSend",String.valueOf(totalSend));
            prop.setProperty("totalRecive",String.valueOf(totalRecive));
            prop.store(out,null);
            out.close();
        }
     }
```

Comment: Which IDE you are Using. Please tell me how, you are testing your code. Inside IDE or Running Out Side IDE?

Comment: On a side note, your code has bad formatting, bad design (Singleton `NewClass.getInstance()`, bad names that do not communicate intent like `NewClass` and a glitch, the `out.close()` call in the last `try` is redundant. Plus, on `main()` the `throws *Exception` are redundant with `throws Exception`.

Comment: @ShineedBasheer Why? What does the IDE have to do with it?

Comment: netbean ide -not work in ide

Comment: Inside IDE its difficult moke gracefull shutdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shutdown hook is not for PC shutdown, it is for the shutdown of the JVM. And it will only work if the JVM is shutdown "gracefully". On JVMs that run on POSIX, graceful shutdown is initiated by a call to `System.exit()` or by sending it the `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT` signal (Ctrl+C). Depending on the OS, it could be that during shutdown of the OS, the JVM is not shutdown at all, or shutdown using the `SIGKILL` signal. In those cases, the shutdown hooks will no be executed.

Comment: does alternative way to save file before shut down pc?

Comment: I do not know of a platform-independent way to do so. Maybe somebody has implemented a cross-platform library for Java (which would have to use JNI), but I do not know.